# Which HP Lovecraft story features a private detective?

Tags: character-identification, h-p-lovecraft

I'm trying to recall, does any HP Lovecraft story actually feature a private detective/private eye (male or female) as the main protagonist? The answer should be specifically HPL and not any derivative works by other authors/artists.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one thing I can say is that it's very unlikely that any HP Lovecraft story had a female protagonist, let alone detective. Most didn't even have a named female character. Even by the standards of the day, there were few women in his works.

Comment: That's a question in itself...which the answer is no female leads. I included both genders just to be inclusive. However, I did want to include a pun about human/other, but thought better of it...till now

Answer (score 14):

The protagonist of Lovecraft's short story *The Horror at Red Hook* is Thomas Malone, a detective with the NYPD.

Comment: It might be worth noting that The Horror at Red Hook is not the most entertaining read, being arguably Lovecraft's most bigoted work, and as such based on his own experiences very directly. Even Lovecraft thought it was bad: "I don't think it is very good."

Answer (score 6):

Thomas Malone is the police detective from The Horror at Red Hook. and there is a retired police detective John R. Legrasse in The Call of Cthulhu in section II, "The Tale of Inspector Legrasse".

There were also unnamed private detectives mentioned in The Case of Charles Dexter Ward.